# Excel VBA - Password Protecting a Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA macro to password protect a sheet in an Excel workbook. It works great except I have the following problem:

If someone types in an incorrect password (even many times), the pop-up box asking for a password will not go away. I'm not sure if there is a way to hide the sheet or exit out of the pop-up if they do not know the password. Otherwise they are stuck in an endless loop with my current code and cannot exit the pop-up box.

I would like it to go the another sheet if the user gets the password incorrect.

Is there any way to do that?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim MySheets As String, Response As String

MySheet = "Balance Sheet"

If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
    ActiveSheet.Visible = False
        Response = InputBox("Only authorized are permitted to view the Balance Sheet. Enter password to view.")
            If Response = "password123" Then
                Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Sheets(MySheet).Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If

    Sheets(MySheet).Activate
    Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True

Else

    Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: What is the desired action if the user wants to stop trying?  Switch to another sheet?  As a sidenote, it's incredibly bad form to hardcode passwords straight into the code; users route around that by just sharing the password.

Comment: Switch to another sheet is perfect! How can you do that?

Comment: Well, you've already hidden it; you do that until they get the password right.  But unless you switch to a different sheet or close the workbook, you're stuck in an infinite loop.  You need to choose an action that breaks out of the cycle.

Comment: Got it now - thanks!

Comment: IMO the only person you're annoying with VBA code protection, is yourself. A typical user wouldn't browse the VBA code anyway, and anyone that wants to access it, will easily be able to - just see the highest scoring link under "Related", in the side bar. Also if a worksheet isn't supposed to be even viewed, then why is it in the same workbook? If you're on a domain, use Windows Authentication and role-based security to grant access to specific network locations, and put the sensitive files there.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon And while a bit harder, you can actually use LDAP in VBA, which removes the need for a password in the first place.  There are sometimes reasons to have protected and unprotected data in the same file.

Comment: @fbueckert there are, but the most common scenario is a sensitive file sitting on a public network share. Restricting access to the file's network location is the simplest, most Windows-idiomatic and secure way to solve authorisation issues.